# Reversible-jump MCMC and Poisson processes

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, poisson-process, jacobian, reversible-jump

Suppose we have a time interval $t \in [0, T]$ in which events occur as a Poisson process with some arbitrary time-dependent rate $\lambda(t)$. These events occur at times $Y=(Y_1, Y_2, \dotso, Y_M)$ for $M$ events, where $Y$ and $M$ are both random variables, and $0 \leq Y_i \leq T$. $T$ is fixed.

The objective is to estimate the number of events $M$ and their times $Y$ using MCMC.

We know that $M$ follows a Poisson distribution with rate $g = \int\limits^T_0 \lambda(s) ds$, and hence $p(M|T) = \frac{e^{-g} g^M}{M!}$.

I believe the joint probability density is:

$$
p(Y,M|T) = p(Y|M,T) p(M|T) = \Big( \prod\limits_{i=1}^M \frac{\lambda(y_i)}{g} \Big) \Big( \frac{e^{-g} g^M}{M!} \Big) = \frac{e^{-g}}{M!} \prod\limits_{i=1}^M \lambda(y_i)
$$

I have confirmed that the integral under this sums to 1, with respect to $Y$ and $M$.

However, I am unable to sample from this distribution using MCMC. Currently, I have two MCMC proposals, and these are selected with equal probabilities at each step in the chain.

1. **Move event.** Sample one of the indices $i$ in $Y$ and sample $Y_i^\prime \sim \text{U}(0,T)$. The Hastings ratio $\frac{q(M,Y|M^\prime,Y^\prime)}{q(M^\prime,Y^\prime|M,Y)} = \frac{\frac{1}{MT}}{\frac{1}{MT}} = 1$. If $M=0$ the proposal is rejected.
2. **Create/destroy event.**

   a. With 0.5 probability, create an event. $M^\prime \leftarrow M+1$. Sample an index $i \sim \text{U}(1, \dotso, M)$ and shift all of the downstream indices up by one: $Y_{i+1}^\prime \leftarrow Y_i, Y_{i+2}^\prime \leftarrow Y_{i+1}, \dotso$. The new value is sampled uniformly $Y_i^\prime \sim \text{U}(0, T)$.

   b. With 0.5 probability, destroy an event. $M^\prime \leftarrow M-1$. Sample an index $i \sim \text{U}(1, \dotso , M)$ and remove it, shifting all of the downstream indices down by one: $Y_{i}^\prime \leftarrow Y_{i+1}, Y_{i+1}^\prime \leftarrow Y_{i+2}, \dotso$. If $M=0$ the proposal is rejected.

   The Hastings-ratio of a birth event is $\frac{q(M,Y|M^\prime,Y^\prime)}{q(M^\prime,Y^\prime|M,Y)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{M+1}}{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{T}} = \frac{T}{M+1}$, and $\frac{M}{T}$ for a death event.

But, as mentioned, this algorithm does not sample the correct distribution (i.e., the estimated number of events $M$ is generally larger than the expected value $g$). I believe the issue comes down to a Jacobian term used in the second operator, which involves a change in dimension. The acceptance probability during MCMC is thus:

$$
\alpha = \min\Big(1, \frac{p(Y^\prime, M^\prime|T) q(M,Y|M^\prime,Y^\prime)}{p(Y, M|T) q(M^\prime,Y^\prime|M,Y)} |J| \Big)
$$

for some Jacobian $J$. But what is $J$? Or perhaps the problem lies elsewhere. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Jordan.  I'm sorry about the unexplained downvote: it's clear to me you have put effort and research into your question (+1).

Comment: Thanks! Happy to clarify if I missed any important details

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a solution now. There were two issues.

First, a quick correction: step 2a should read "Sample an index $i \sim U(1, 2, \dotso, M, M+1)$", rather than $M$, because there are $M+1$ possible places a new element can be inserted in a list with $M$ elements.

Second, the creation proposal kernel was not taking the random indexing of this new event into account, but the reverse proposal (destroy) was. The corrected Hastings ratio of the birth-death proposal is:

$$
\frac{q(M,Y|M',Y')}{q(M',Y'|M,Y)} = \frac{\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{M+1}}{\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{M+1} \frac{1}{T}} = T \text{ for a birth and } \frac{1}{T} \text{ for a death}.
$$

Expectation of M and estimated number of events are now the same. Figure below is from 100 MCMC replicates across 100 expected values.

[image]